# How do I delete lines of text with batch and create line breaks?

Tags: batch-file

I need to do a batch file which copys a `.txt` file and edits the new file.
In the new file the first two lines should be deleted.
After that there needs to be a line break after every 355th character.

So the source `.txt` looks something like this:

```
useless line 1
useless line 2
single line with 1516539 characters....
```

And the new .txt file should look like this:

```
Line 1 with 355 characters
Line 2 with 355 characters
Line 3 with 355 characters
Line 4 with 355 characters
.
.
.
```

This is my `.bat` so far.

```
@echo off
copy Y:\Dat_6\Log6.txt C:\Users\<user>\Desktop

pause
```

Comment: in `cmd`, the max length of a variable is limited (somewhat above 8000), which limits your options. Consider using PowerShell.

Comment: I won't try to write the 355 character part, but for skipping the first two lines: `for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%a in (Y:\Dat_6\Log6.txt) do echo %%a > C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\Log6.txt`

Comment: To essentially do what you want to do you would need to read the file character by character or read the whole file into memory first. You might be able to do that with [JREPL.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044)

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong: `%%a` can't hold a 1,5 million char line. (besides your code would append a space to each line, which might be unwanted and troublesome)

Comment: Fair comment, but as you pointed out in your first comment, the only way to fix that would be to use powershell.  I think my solution is about as close as pure batch script is gonna get you.  That said, I recognize that it's still far from a complete solution as I only address half the problem, and there are limitations as you've pointed out.

Comment: How long are the useless two lines?

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong: I didn't say PowerShell was the *only* option. Batch just isn't a good tool for this (not impossible though, as aschipfl showed), but almost any other programming language would be a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

The following batch script reads the long line of your text file by `set /P`, which reads it in portions of about 1K characters/bytes, does that in a loop, and returns portions of text in a nested loop:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=Y:\Dat_6\Log6.txt"
set /A "_NUM=2"   & rem // (number of lines to skip)
set /A "_LEN=355" & rem // (number of characters per line)

rem // Do file processing in sub-routine:
< "%_FILE%" call :PROCESS

endlocal
exit /B


:PROCESS
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "PREV="
    rem // Skip first few (short) lines:
    for /L %%I in (1,1,%_NUM%) do set /P LINE=""
:PROCESS_GET
    rem // Read more text:
    set "LINE=" & set /P LINE=""
    rem // Stop if no (more) text is available:
    if not defined LINE (
        if defined PREV echo(!PREV!
        endlocal & exit /B
    )
    rem // Prepend previous unhandled text:
    set "LINE=!PREV!!LINE!"
:PROCESS_CUT
    rem // Check whether more text is needed:
    if "!LINE:~%_LEN%!"=="" set "PREV=!LINE!" & goto :PROCESS_GET
    rem // Return a text portion:
    echo(!LINE:~,%_LEN%!
    rem // Split off remaining text:
    set "LINE=!LINE:~%_LEN%!"
    rem // Process remaining text:
    goto :PROCESS_CUT
    endlocal
    exit /B
```

Note that this script is completely untested (yet)…

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, I would suggest [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) for this task. To keep this on topic, you can run it directly from your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```batch-file
@"%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile ^
 "Get-Content \"Y:\Dat_6\Log6.txt\" | ForEach-Object {" ^
  "$line = $_; for ($i = 0; $i -lt $line.Length; $i += 355) {" ^
   "$length = [Math]::Min(355, $line.Length - $i); $line.SubString($i, $length)" ^
  "} } | Select-Object -Skip 2 |" ^
 "Set-Content \"P:\ath To\something.ext\" -Encoding ASCII"
```

Here you'd modify output file path on line `6`, and if necessary your input filename on line `2`. *If you do that, please note that each path should be enclosed in escaped doublequotes, `\"`*

Comment: you could replace each escaped doublequote `\"` wit a singlequote `'` for readabilty

Comment: Purely preference, in this case, just not mine.